# Save/Fetch List even after Android reboot

Tags: java, android, file

I am saving and writing an ArrayList using the following code to a file. This method works to sustain the list only when the application is backgrounded(onStop(), i presume), but when I reboot the phone, my list is lost:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> loadListFromFile(
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> masterlistrev) {

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(serfilename);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        masterlistrev = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) ois
                .readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return masterlistrev;
}

private void writeListToFile(
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> masterlistrev, Context ctx,
        String filename) {

    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = ctx.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(masterlistrev);
        oos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    writeListToFile((ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) painItems,
            getApplicationContext(), serfilename);
}
protected void onDestroy(){

    writeListToFile((ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) painItems,
            getApplicationContext(), serfilename);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

EDIT-- **ON CREATE METHOD**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addscreen);
    // getPainItems from the saved file
    if (loadListFromFile((ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) painItems) != null)
        painItems = loadListFromFile((ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) painItems);
    // if it's the first time opening the app, then go to 'AddMyInfo.class'
    serfilename = "hello";
    SharedPreferences settings = this.getSharedPreferences("MyApp", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor e = settings.edit();
    boolean firstrun = settings.getBoolean("firstrun", true);
    if (firstrun) {
        e.putBoolean("firstrun", false);
        e.commit();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddMyInfo.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    // initialize painTitle and set its font
    painTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.painTitle);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "Chantelli_Antiqua.ttf");
    painTitle.setTypeface(font);
    listthings = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listthings);
    from = new String[] { "row_1", "row_2" };
    to = new int[] { R.id.row1, R.id.row2 };

    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, painItems, R.layout.mylistlayout,
            from, to);
    listthings.setAdapter(adapter);
    listthings.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    listthings.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);

    addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    listthings.setChoiceMode(CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

}
```

As you can see, I have overriden the OnStop() and OnDestroy methods to try to do this. I have put writeListToFile() in the OnCreate() Method. Any solution appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, is it possible upon relaunch you are writing your empty array list to your file and subsequently trying to access said list? I have a feeling everything is writing and reading correctly but there is a logical flaw either destroying your text file (MODE_PRIVATE erases everything in a file when you call it, while MODE_APPEND writes to the end of it) or writing a blank arrayList to it. Could I see your onCreate() Method?

Comment: done, and I mean loadListFromFile() method in the OnCreate(). Should I change `MODE_PRIVATE` ( in writeListToFile()) to MODE_APPEND?

Comment: well, If you want to be able to add entries without deleting everything thats already there then yes, you should have it be in MODE_APPEND. as for why your read() method in onCreate is failing Im not entirely sure. However it seems odd to me you are not passing a filename to your read method. I would also suggest creating an isEmpty() method that checks to see if your file is empty. you can do open an input stream and reader and just check : reader.readLine() != -1 (indicating an empty file), because you might have a pointer error where your OIS is pointing to the end of the file after the

Comment: initial if () statement call in onCreate()

Comment: I am not trying to add anything -- as long as I am able to save the new file, even if it replaces the old one, the list should save; MODE_PRIVATE seems ok. you say i am not passing a filename to my read method, but I am : `painItems`

Comment: It seems to me you arent passing a file... Look at your loadListFromFile method, it doesnt have a File parameter.. instead I think it is assuming painItems is the name of your ArrayList. This (or a similar issue) actually makes a lot of sense with your problem. onCreate() is only called when your application fully launches from a dead state, aka when you reboot your phone. and because your data exists when you merely go to home (in which case the intent is likely still active) you dont call onCreate() when you enter your app again. This tells you that your file is most likely being

Comment: erased within your onCreate() method, particularly when you try and load data from it.